# Can I set only "n" number of rows to be visible in a flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container with the following CSS:

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Is there any way to limit it to only displaying N rows, with the remaining rows not showing? I'd like to avoid setting a fixed height, as the elements in the container have potentially differing heights (which might lead to different rows being different heights).

Comment: add a height to your container and then set overflow to hidden

Comment: doable with CSS grid but you won't have the same behavior as flexbox

Answer (score -2):

Is that what you meant?. excuse me if I got it wrong.

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child{
 display: none;
}

.child:nth-child(2){
 display : block;
}
```

```html
<div class ="container">
  <div class="child">I am a child</div>
  <div class="child">I am a child too</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).